# Count consecutive changes in a sequence using an index

Tags: r, indexing, sequence

Using R, what would be the best way to count the number of changes in a sequence of character values from an index. For example, I have a fixed number of sites:

> ```
> sites<-as.factor(LETTERS[seq(from=1,to=20)])
> ```

From those sites, some are protected, while others are open to fishing,

> ```
> protected<-as.factor(c("A","D","E","M","L","S"))
> ```

Using a simulation, I got this sequence of sites (a combination of protected/non protected sites)

> ```
> result<-as.factor(c("A","A","A","B","C","D","D","L","L","F","F","T","S","N"))
> ```

Basically, I want to count how many times in my result sequence, there is a change from "protected" to "non-protected" sites. In this example, the answer that I am looking would be 3, since "A", which is a protected site is moving to "B" that is non-protected (one move), "B" is moving to "C" (both unprotected so is not changing),..., "L" to "N" (two moves), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find where you change from Protected to Non-protected with %in% and diff.  Then count up the values you want.  Here, Protected ->  non-protected gives -1.

```
sum(diff(result %in% protected) < 0)
```

Comment: There is an error when I try to use this code "could not find function "diff<-"?

Comment: No diff<- in use here.  Did you perhaps mistakenly type <- instead of < in the line?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I just saw my mistake. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciated!